# How can I remove table borders with DocxJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docx

Let's say I want to remove all of the borders from this table:

```
---------------------------
|   image    |    text    |
---------------------------
```

Following the documentation online: https://docx.js.org/#/usage/tables

```
new Table({
   borders: {
              top: {style: BorderStyle.NONE},
              bottom: {style: BorderStyle.NONE},
              left: {style: BorderStyle.NONE},
              right: {style: BorderStyle.NONE},
            },
    rows: [
      new TableRow({
        children: [
          new TableCell({
            children: [
              new Paragraph({ children: [some_image_file] }),
            ],
          }),
          new TableCell({
            children: [
              new Paragraph({ text: "text" }),
            ],
          }),
        ],
      }),
     ],
  })
```

This gives:

```
   image    |    text
```

According to the documentation, moving the border options inside the `TableCell` should impact the cell's borders, but I see no results when I do so. Any ideas how to achieve a table without any borders?

Comment: Hey! I'll be honest, I haven't heard of docx.js, but looking over the documentation, have you tried adding size: 0 to the border properties? Just a hunch.

Comment: @cbloss793 Just checked and this works! The strange thing is that for the Table itself you don't have to specify the size for the border to disappear (as shown above). However, for the cells it seems that you must specify size (and I think setting `color: "FFFFFF"` is a good idea just in case). Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You're welcome! Sometimes things like this happens where you have to jump through hoops for something so simple. Can you give me a +1 (the up triangle) on the comment? Thanks!

Comment: @cbloss793 Done!

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @cbloss793, It seems that border options for `TableCell` must also contain the `size: 0` attribute to remove the corresponding border. I also added `color: "FFFFFF"` just to be safe.

```
...
new TableCell({
   borders: {
          top: {style: BorderStyle.NONE, size: 0, color: "FFFFFF"},
          bottom: {style: BorderStyle.NONE, size: 0, color: "FFFFFF"},
          left: {style: BorderStyle.NONE, size: 0, color: "FFFFFF"},
          right: {style: BorderStyle.NONE, size: 0, color: "FFFFFF"},
        },
...
```

Comment: the only change that works is the white color

Answer (score 0):

For me, using DocxJS v. 8.2.3, using `BorderStyle.NIL` worked to remove cell borders.

```
new TableCell({
   borders: {
          top: {style: BorderStyle.NIL },
          bottom: {style: BorderStyle.NIL },
          left: {style: BorderStyle.NIL },
          right: {style: BorderStyle.NIL },
        },
```

I had no need to set either the `size` or the `color`.

Now users can print on buff colored paper and not see faint white cell borders.

Comment: `new Table({
    borders: {
        top: {style: BorderStyle.NIL},
        bottom: {style: BorderStyle.NIL},
        left: {style: BorderStyle.NIL},
        right: {style: BorderStyle.NIL},
        insideVertical: {style: BorderStyle.NIL},
 },
`
Nice find, thank you. Additionally, you can even skip all borders if you add insideVertical and/or insideHorizontal and add this to the table's border property itself.